# adding css class (or style) based on the variable using directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a scenario where I have to use ng-style (or ng-class) multiple times based on the variable.

But this causes a lot of pain for me as for the same functionality  am writing everytime (for every widget) ng-class.

So was wondering if there is a way to get rid of that. I know I can create a C type directive to achieve that. But this doesnt seems to be working.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-style="expanded1 ? {{'height': viewPortHeight} : ''" ng-click="expanded1=!expanded1">Panel 1</div>
..........
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-style="expanded2 ? {{'height': viewPortHeight} : ''" ng-click="expanded2=!expanded2">Panel 2</div>
```

Can I have a direcive (C or A), which can see the variable "expanded" (for this element only) and add the style to this element.

I tried this, but that doesn't seems to be working

== Directive

```
(function (app) {
  app.directive('expandWidget', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('expanded', function(expanded){
                if(expanded)
                    element.css('height', 'viewPortHeight')
                else element.css('height', '300px')
            })
          }
      }
    })
})
<div class="panel panel-primary" expand-widget ng-click="expanded1=!expanded1">Panel 1</div>
```

I am fine with some other approach as well, which can serve above purpose.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? `panel panel-primary` smells like bs3.x ..?

Comment: yes..I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I took a crack at your problem, Hope this helps.

.directive('expandWidget', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

```
  var expanded = attrs['expanded'] === 'true' || false;
  var exapndedHeight = (attrs['exapndedHeight'] || 600) + 'px';
  var collapsedHeight = (attrs['collapsedHeight'] || 50) + 'px';

  function setHeight() {
    element[0].style.height = expanded ? exapndedHeight :  collapsedHeight;
  }

  function toggle() {
    expanded = !expanded
    setHeight();
  }

  element[0].addEventListener( attrs['trigger'] || 'click', toggle);
  setHeight();
}
```

}
})

https://plnkr.co/edit/Hthl41G0dbZhk8v2BDFv

Answer (score 0):

You can have a scope variable :

```
$scope.expanded = false;
```

pass that as attribute to the directive :

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" 
   expand-widget 
   expanded="{{ expanded }}" 
   ng-click="expanded = !expanded">
```

use `attrs.$observe` to test if the expanded attribute changes, and do whatever you want to do with the element(s) when it happens :

```
.directive('expandWidget', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      expanded: '@'  
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('expanded', function(expanded){
        expanded = expanded == 'true'
        if (expanded) { 
          element[0].style.height = '250px'
        } else {           
          element[0].style.height = '100px'
        }   
      })
    }    
  }
})
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/0FHVGwQx7jogHyGol7fN?p=preview**

`$scope.expanded` is just an example. If you have many panels you could have a

```
$scope.panels = {
  expanded1: true,
  expanded2: false,
  expanded3: false
  ...
}
```

and target `$scope.panels.expanded2` etc instead. I was not sure what you mean by "viewPortHeight" so I just set a arbitrary height in the example code.

---

If you want to toggle classes instead of mingling with the elements `style` you can do this :

```
attrs.$observe('expanded', function(expanded){
   expanded = expanded == 'true'
   if (expanded) { 
     $(element)
       .removeClass('defaultClass')
       .addClass('expandedClass')
   } else {            
     $(element)
       .removeClass('expandedClass')
       .addClass('defaultClass')
   }   
})
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/UZWPYoTOu0ABqnVqrmw3?p=preview**

It is OK to use jQuery here since you already are using bootstrap.